# Returns none when doing a while loop in python

Tags: python, syntax, while-loop

A game for getting highest score possible without getting the same numbers. Did this in class as a task and when running through while loop you get the printed bit then on the next line `None`. Please help as no one in our A-level class nor teacher could work out where it has gone wrong..

```
from random import randint
game = True
score = 0

die1 = randint(1,6)
die2 = randint(1,6)

while game == True:
    if die1 == die2:
        score = 0
        game = False
    else:
        score = score + die1 + die2
        goagain = input(print("do you want another go? Y or N"))
        if goagain == "N" or goagain == "n":
            game = False
        else:
            print("your current score is:" , score)

print("game over!! \nYour score is:" , score)
```

Comment: Remove the `print` inside of your `input`.

Comment: Also there is no `return` in your piece of code. What is returning `None`? Do you mean that the `score` is `None`?

Comment: And you are only rolling the dice one time. For your sake, I hope this is not the code your teacher is looking at.

Comment: thanks, Rawing. removing the print in the input worked. thanks alot!!

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the "print" from within the input to get rid of the None:

```
from random import randint
game = True
score = 0

die1 = randint(1,6)
die2 = randint(1,6)

while game == True:
    if die1 == die2:
        score = 0
        game = False
    else:
        score = score + die1 + die2
        goagain = input("do you want another go? Y or N")
        if goagain == "N" or goagain == "n":
            game = False
        else:
            print("your current score is:" , score)

print("game over!! \nYour score is:" , score)
```

But I don't think this is what you want - you don't reroll the die, so you are just constantly adding the same number to the score until the user stops. I think you want to put the die rolls inside of the loop, like this:

```
from random import randint
game = True
score = 0

while game == True:
    die1 = randint(1,6)
    die2 = randint(1,6)
    if die1 == die2:
        score = 0
        game = False
    else:
        score = score + die1 + die2
        goagain = input("do you want another go? Y or N")
        if goagain == "N" or goagain == "n":
            game = False
        else:
            print("your current score is:" , score)

print("game over!! \nYour score is:" , score)
```

Finally, you don't print out the score before asking the user if they want another go, which seems weird especially on the first loop. You can just move your print statement outside of the else:

```
from random import randint
game = True
score = 0

while game == True:
    die1 = randint(1,6)
    die2 = randint(1,6)
    if die1 == die2:
        score = 0
        game = False
    else:
        score = score + die1 + die2
        print("your current score is:" , score)
        goagain = input("do you want another go? Y or N")
        if goagain == "N" or goagain == "n":
            game = False

print("game over!! \nYour score is:" , score)
```